# Page getting refreshed/reloaded many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am learning JavaScript and backbone.js and trying to develop one small web app. 
But the problem is that my page (graph) is getting reloaded many times (more than expected). So page automatically reloads many times (super fast) before the page gets stable and graph is displayed. When I say "Reload of browser" I mean to say the reload icon of google chrome refresh icon refreshes/ (does forward rotation, back rotation) many times and finally the data gets displayed.

Below is short version of what I have tried till now. Since I am in the learning phase, I might not have made correct coding standard. Bear with me on that.

So, I have to display one graph on the front page (Later I need to add more graphs on the same page). The data for the graph is coming from REST Service.

**HTML:**

I have one anchor, and one template to display the graph data.

```
 <div id ="chartAnchor1"></div>
<script id="myChart-template" type="text/template">
    <canvas id="lineChart"></canvas>
    </script>
```

**ViewModel**

This is for graph specific data:

```
  var firstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
    events: {
  'click .Refresh': 'fetchModelData'
    },
      fetchModelData: function() {
      this.model.initialize();
    },
    render: function() 
    {
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
          datasets: [{
            data: this.model.attributes.incThisYear
          }, {
            data: this.model.attributes.incLastYear
          }]
        },
                labelString: 'Income in $'
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    },
   initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, "fetchModelData");
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    }
  });

  return firstSubViewModel;
});
```

**Controller:**

```
  var ch = new dashboardModel.chart({});
  if (// some condition) {
    var data = { // some data};
    ch.fetch(data)
  }     
  //Main Graph on Dashboard
  new firstSubViewModel({
    el: '#chartAnchor1',
    model: ch
  });

});
```

**Model:**
I have one model class which gets the data from REST Service.

Question: Page is getting refreshed some 5-6 times and finally graph gets loaded perfectly.

FootNote: Is there any problem in my render function. Kindly guide.

Comment: What is `fetchModelData`? how/when is it invoked? why have you defined it twice? `this.model.initialize();` - why are you manually invoking model's initialize? Are you aware that you have written `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. The  twice written method was typo while pasting the code in SO. I took it out. Also, do you want me to comment the `fetchModelData` function. I thought I need to initialize the model and call it from `_.bindAll()`

Comment: @TJ: there is one refresh button near graph which when click refreshes the graph with current value in DB. I have called `fetchModelData` when Refresh button/event is invoked. Kindly see the code once `I have added the missing `refresh event` snippet in the code. Have I done some silly stuff. Please guide.

Comment: Everything is getting displayed fine, But the refresh/reload icon of Chrome browser flickers super fast couple of time before graph shows up. :/

Comment: And when I add more graph to the home page that flicker/Refresh in chrome in opening the page gets multiplied.

Comment: I am a newbie. I am still learning all this by doing. Have not studied theory much. But I will pay heed to what you have told. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bound the model's change event to the view's render method with  `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);` this means for every change on model, view will re-render.

And you're passing model attributes directly to some `Chart()` function. We don't know what's going on inside it, but chances are it's updating model attributes many times as part of chart drawing and obviously each change causes another `render` which invokes the `Chart()` method again, which invokes the `render` and hence creates a render loop that is likely as long as the number of changes made to model by `Chart()` function.

Either remove `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);` or use model's [`toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) method to get a **copy** of it's data and pass it to `chart()` method for drawing. Use cases like this is the reason why `toJSON()` method exists.

---

Another issue is handling the asynchronous `fetch`, I think `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);` was your attempt to handle this, but it's wrong. Either you should listen to events such as `sync` instead, like

```
this.model.on('sync', this.render, this);
```

or do something like:

```js
var ch = new dashboardModel.chart({});
/* ---------------------------^ this is the actual model constructor?
 Then what's dashboardModel?! Bad naming ;) */

ch.fetch({
  success: function(model, response) {
    new firstSubViewModel({
      el: '#chartAnchor1',
      model: ch
    });
  }
});
```

---

Apart from that you should not manually initialize models. It's a one time activity handled by Backbone.js and only *one time initialization code* should be added inside it. I can't even think of what you were trying to achieve by manually invoking `initialize` on an already *initialized* model.

To fetch data from your persistence layer you should be using `fetch()` method.

```
fetchModelData: function() {
  this.model.fetch({/* options */});
}
```

---

Your code in controller has many issues. It seems to try and `fetch()` a model with some **data**?, but `fetch` method only accepts *options*, mostly for customizing and handling the AJAX call like the ones I've used above (Maybe they were actually options but you named it *data*?! Ignore this one in that case).

Also there's a view hanging around with no references for cleanup, a direct reference to DOM via `el` option which will cause issues if you create another instance of `firstSubViewModel`, use of `on` instead of [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) etc  all leading to classic Backbone.js bugs like memory leaks, issues with events and such.

All those can't be handled in an answer so I suggest reading the docs properly and doing some research about common Backbone.js issues.

---

Side note: According to common naming conversion, `firstSubViewModel` should be `FirstSubViewModel` because it's a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to read the answer properly and will let you know if I get any doubt in understanding above concepts.