# Display data in tabular format using templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, frontend

I am new to Backbone.js. I have some data coming from REST Service and I want to display them into tabular format using Templates in Backbone.js. Can someone help me on how can I loop through and print the data in tabular format. Below is what I have achieved till now.

**Model**

```
   define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
      var abcViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
       template: _.template($('#abc-template').html()),
        render: function() {
          console.log(this.model.toJSON());
          data = this.model.toJSON();
          var html = this.template(data);
          $(this.el).html(html);
        },
        initialize: function() {
          this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        }
      });
  return abcViewModel;
});
```

Output of `console.log(this.model.toJSON()` is

[image]

**HTML/Template**

```
  <script id="abc-template" type="text/template">
     <%= data.incThisYear %>
      <%= data.incLastYear %>
    </script>
```

**Output on Screen at present**

[image]

**But I want the output in tabular format**

```
         |   incThisYear  |       incLastYear
    Jan  |                |
    Feb  |                |
    Mar  |                | 
and so on..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle this.  One of the quickest would be to add a loop to your template that would go through each month of the year and display the month, as well as the corresponding inc this year (if found) and inc. last year in a table:

```
<script id="abc-template" type="text/template">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Inc. This Year</th>
      <th>Inc. Last Year</th>
    </tr>
    <% ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'].forEach(function(month, i) { %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= month %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= incThisYear[i] || '-'%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= incLastYear[i] || '-'%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% }) %>
  </table>
</script>
```

I put together a quick fiddle to show this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hy8otewm/

Comment: Can you kindly look into this issue please.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252794/page-getting-refreshed-reloaded-many-times